# How to put a variable in a Neo4j cypher query for a repository

Tags: java, spring, repository, neo4j

I am using spring neo4j.  I have a `repository` class that extends `GraphRepository<T>`.  I want to delete a specific object based on the `uid` in the arguments to the method below.

```
public interface TypeRepository extends GraphRepository<Type> {

    @Query("START n=node:node_auto_index(uid=uidValueYAA)" +
                "MATCH n-[r]-()" +
                "DELETE n, r")
    public void deleteByUid(String uidValueYAA);
}
```

Note:  my persisted class has an index annotation like the following:

```
@GraphId
private Long id;
@Indexed(unique=true) private String uid;
```

I get the following exception when I use the method like so:

```
typeRepository.deleteByUid(uid);

//The Exception
string literal or parameter expected|"START n=node:node_auto_index(uid=uidValueYAA)MATCH n-[r]-()DELETE n, r"|
```

How can I use the method to delete a specific node based on the `uid` that I pass to the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use {0} instead of the name as shown below

```
@Query("START n=node:node_auto_index(uid={0})" +
                "MATCH n-[r]-()" +
                "DELETE n, r")
public void deleteByUid(String uidValueYAA);
```

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
    @Query("START n=node:node_auto_index(uid={uidValueYAA})" +
                "MATCH n-[r]-()" +
                "DELETE n, r")
    public void deleteByUid(@Param("uidValueYAA") String uidValueYAA);
```